# Cannot find subschema for root field

Tags: schema, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

Im using `graphql-tools` package and I'm trying to stitch a subquery into a resolver of another entity.

the query I would like to stitch:

```
ordersQueries: {
       getOrdersByDates(startDate, endDate): [Order]
       ......
}
```

I would like to stitch the `getOrdersByDates`, in the `userInfoResolver` like that:

```
export const userInfoResolver = (mergeInfo) => ({
    UserInfo:{
        orders: {
            fragment: `...`
            resolve(parent, args, context, info) {
                ...
                return mergeInfo.delegate(
                    'query',
                    'getOrdersByDates'
                );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But I can't because it's not defined in the microservice root queries.

So I tried this instead:

```
export const userInfoResolver = (mergeInfo) => ({
    UserInfo:{
        orders: {
            fragment: `...`
            resolve(parent, args, context, info) {
                ...
                return mergeInfo.delegate(
                    'query',
                    'ordersQueries.getOrdersByDates'
                );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But the result is:

```
"Cannot find subschema for root field "query.ordersQueries.getOrdersByDates".
```

So how can I access the `getOrdersByDates` subquery and stitch it into my `UserInfo` query?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your solution is to add the `getOrdersByDates` to context, then call it as `context.getOrdersByDates` instead.